# Two double spaces between paragraphs

Tags: spacing, paragraphs

How can I set two double spaces between all paragraphs in a report? I have already set double spaces between lines with this command:

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
```

Comment: Does `\setlength{\parskip}{<insert length here>}` not do what you want?

Comment: Please don’t use double spacing between lines. It looks ugly and is quite unnecessary because LaTeX produces readable documents even with single spacing between lines. (This is unrelated to spaces between *paragraphs*, to which Willie has already posted the solution.)

Comment: @Willie: Setting simply `\parskip` is not recommendable since it also affects lists, headings and ToC, LoF, LoT. It is better to use the »parskip« package.

Comment: @konrad: The guidelines for submitting my report states that I should complsorily have double space between lines, and 2 double spaces between paragraphs.

Comment: willie & thorsten: I am little confused about what is the exact lenght in numbers for 2 double spaces.

Comment: @Konrad: Of course double spacing is horrible, but sometimes people are required to do it. We don't know if that is the case here. So while your advice is excellent, it may not hurt to tone it down a little bit.

Comment: @nixnotwin: Use `2\baselineskip` for that.

Comment: @Thorsten: I didn't know that package, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Thorsten alludes to above, the idea is to use the `parskip` package since it redefines list items and a couple other things to cope with the large increase in between each "paragraph". I wonder if it shouldn't redefine more, such as spacing around a figure, but I haven't investigated its limitations.

Unfortunately, the amount of space added between the paragraphs in `parskip` is fixed; here's how you'd change it:

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{parskip}
\parskip=2\baselineskip \advance\parskip by 0pt plus 2pt
```

The additional stretch will help to jiggle things around on the page in case you don't have an exact integer number of paragraph lines of text worth of content (e.g., there exists a table or figure on the page).