# Report custom format

Tags: fonts, formatting, report

I'm new to LaTeX and I want create a report for my college. The format specified is as follows:

- Left Margin – 1.5 inch
- Right Margin - 0.5 inch
- Top Margin – 1 inch
- Bottom Margin – 1 inch
- Font - Times New Roman
- All main headings uppercase 14 (Bold)
- All Sub main headings uppercase 12 (Bold)
- Matter 12 (Regular)
- Line Spacing – 1.5
- Paragraph Spacing 1.5
- Each table and figure should be numbered

For margins I've used the following code:

```
 \usepackage[top=1.00in, bottom=1.00in, left=1.50in,right=0.50in]{geometry}
```

But I don't know what to do for the rest.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is actually a few questions that have already been answered. To use Times New Roman, see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172722/times-new-roman-font-in-pdflatex); to format section headers, have a look at the [`sectsty`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) package; to set the main text in 12 pt font, add the `12pt` option to your document class invocation; text spacing is [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/819/double-line-spacing); paragraph spacing is [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6556/two-double-spaces-between-paragraphs).

Comment: Also, figures and tables are automatically numbered if you place them in the `figure` and `table` environments respectively.

Comment: It should be noted, that regarding the sizes of fonts, line and paragraph spacings, there might be differences to the often MS-WORD dominated world, e.g. 14pt main headings produced by LaTeX might not be the 14pt request of the format. If nobody controlls this actually, there is no problem of course ;-)

Comment: To follow up on Christian Hupfer's point: If the main font size of your LaTeX document is `12pt`, then the instruction `\large` (to be used for section-level headers) will produce a font size of `14.4pt` rather than `14pt`. As Christian notes, though, it's not likely that anyone in your college will spot the difference between text rendered at 14pt and at 14.4pt, is it?

Comment: @Mico: Yes, such a small difference will hardly be noted, but I believe, line spacings could be more 'critical'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Summarizing and combining the comments that have been posted so far, the following setup may work for you. It assumes that you're using pdfLaTeX and that you have a reasonably current TeX distribution. (If you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, different instructions would apply for the font-loading portion of the preamble.)

There's one crucial piece of information missing in what you've provided so far: The size of the page. Is it A4, A5, US Letter, US Legal, or something else? You should provide this piece of information when loading the `geometry` package.

By the way, do note that opinions vary greatly on what exactly "line spacing 1.5" means. In the code below, I suggest using `\setstretch{1.5}`. However, `\onehalfspacing` (to be executed immediately after `\begin{document}`) may in fact be more appropriate for you. I suggest checking back with your college to clarify what is required.

It's also not clear to me what "Paragraph spacing 1.5" is supposed to mean. For now, I'm suggesting keeping interparagraph and intraparagraph line spacing the same. However, it may turn out that what's required is that interparagraph line spacing must be 50% larger than intraparagraph spacing; if that's the case, add the instruction `\setlength\parskip{0.5\baselineskip}` -- and prepare yourself for some really ugly-looking documents...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  % 12pt: main font size

% dimensions of text block
\usepackage[vmargin=1in, left=1.5in, right=0.5in]{geometry}

% font family: Times Roman
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % or: mathptmx
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % important if your docs contain special characters
\usepackage[utf8{inputenc}

% size and weight of font to be used in section headers
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\large\bfseries} 
\subsectionfont{\normalsize\bfseries}

% line spacing
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5} % or:  \onehalfspacing -- opinions vary...

% If you use the table and figure environments along with
% \caption commands, the floats will be numbered automatically
\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text
\begin{document}\onehalfspacing
\section{A first section}
\subsection{A first subsection}
\lipsum[2-3]
\section{Another section}
\subsection{Another subsection}
\lipsum[3-4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: By line spacing and paragraph spacing they mean interparagraph and intraparagraph spacing (I think so). And the unit 1.5 is same as in MS word. Let us take it as first case.

What if they mean line spacing to be between margin and chapter or chapter and section or whatever there is ?